# Remove HSlider horizontal control line

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Does anyone know how can the horizontal control line be removed or made invisible.

What am trying to say is, I just want to show the drag-thumb and not the horizontal line.

Is there a way to do so, with out using skins?

Regards
Zeeshan

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
HSlider
{
    trackSkin:ClassReference(null);
    trackHighlightSkin:ClassReference(null);
}
```